# Unauthorized App in Twitter using Twitterizer

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, twitterizer

I am using the Twitterizer to Post and Update on the Twitter.
I need to post an Image on the Twitter i am using following link to Post on the Twitter.

[YouTube Video Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGEA1sgMMqU)

[Source Code Link](http://www.markhagan.me/Samples/Grant-Access-And-Tweet-As-Twitter-User-ASPNet)

I am doing exactly the same thing as shown in the Video. but still not able to Post on the Twitter. I am getting Unauthorized in response.result

Might be there is an issue with the Time I am sending you the screen regarding this. Please Help me.

Screens FYI

Date Issue Screen(Hopefully not)
[image: Date Issue Screen(Hopefully not)]

Unauthorized Screen
[image: Unauthorized Screen]

Comment: Did you change `oauth_consumer_key` & `oauth_consumer_secret`? Also did you change the permission of the app from `Read(default)` to `Read and write`?

Comment: Ya I have tried all the things but still getting the same result.

Comment: Check the comments on that article. It seems it won't work.